# I want to print the ainput at the end line and it should form a sum solution with answer JAVA ARRAY

Tags: java

I am having trouble printing all the array at the bottom.

Source Code:

```
import java.util.*;
public class Main {
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
     Scanner x = new Scanner (System.in);
     System.out.print("Enter the number of bills: ");
     int numbills = x.nextInt();
     
     int myArray[]=new int[numbills];
     int sum = 0;

     for(int i = 0; i<myArray.length;i++)
      {
         System.out.print("Bill #" +(i+1)+": ");
         myArray[i]=x.nextInt();
         sum = sum+myArray[i];

         if (i<myArray.length-1)
         {
            
            System.out.print(myArray[i]);
            System.out.print("+ ");
         }
      }
      
    
      System.out.print(" = "+sum);
   
   }      
}
```

Output:

```
Enter the number of bills: 2
Bill #1: 100
100+ Bill #2: 200
 = 300
```

Possible output:

```
Enter the number of bills: 2
Bill #1: 100
Bill #2: 200
100 + 200 = 300
```

Comment: Just a little syntactic sugar as well as more readability: Instead of having a `for` that defines an index, makes sure it is less than `myArray.length`, and increments the index, you can use the for each statement: `for(int currentBill : myArray)`. This statement is preferable in every way possible. It takes away the complexity of having to understand the index is going into the array to operate over the entire array - understood only after looking into the loop. Instead, for each immediately documents you are iterating over the contents of the array without looking inside the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is you are taking input and printing it in the same for-loop. 
You can use 2 for-loop(one for input and one for output).
or you can store it in string in same loop and print it after loop ends.

```
String sumstr = "";
for(int i = 0; i<myArray.length;i++)
{
   System.out.print("Bill #" +(i+1)+": ");
   myArray[i]=x.nextInt();
   sum = sum+myArray[i];

   if (i>0)
   {
       sumstr = sumstr + "+";
   }
   sumstr = sumstr + myArray[i];
}
System.out.print(sumstr + " = "+sum);
```